# OnClickListener in android app fails

Tags: android, onclicklistener

When I start my android application on my smartphone the system always is closing my app and it says: "Sorry. YourApplication was closed."

It is because of the OnClickListener, but why?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addTodo = (Button) findViewById((R.id.addTodoButton));
    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("SEAS!");
        }
    });
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sstodo.app/sstodo.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sstodo.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
```

Buttons (used in a alet dialog):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/addTodoButton"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        style="@style/addButtonStyle"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        style="@style/cancelButtonStyle"
        />
```

Comment: Also show activity_main.xml...and remove double brackets for Button addTodo.

Comment: first thing remove double brackets. second thing post the stacktrace and third thing get used to using Log.i/e/v etc rather than println while working with android

Comment: I guess you cancel is null. Show us more to be sure.

Comment: @Houssni I'm risking to get flagged here, but NO, I wasn't.

Comment: yeah both are null. but why?

Comment: line 24 is the onClickListener line

Comment: Yeah, anyway when you launch your application w/o onClickListener you see the layout?

Comment: I open my app.
In the app is a button, when I click then there appears a alert dialog. with a cancel and a add button.

Comment: and they're null. but i implement them in the create method

Comment: two button appear in alert dialog? if it be, you have to create this dialog layout (called dLayout) and inflate the layout that contain 2 buttons in 'dLayout'.
 You need to imagine: 2 button are appear in Alert Dialog. But you findviewbyId outside in Alert Dialog Layout, so Null problem appear

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() { 
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) 
{

System.out.println("SEAS!"); }
 });
```

Comment: Change your OnClickListener to             View.OnClickListener